# Setting output format on MousePosition control

Tags: openlayers

Having a bit of trouble getting the format to change on the MousePosition control. I want to change it to {y}N, {x}E but can't quite work it out.

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
    // be placed within the map.
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    undefinedHTML: ''
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, found how to do it... see below.

```
var template = '{y}N, {x}E';
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: function (coordinate) {
        return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, template, 4)
    },
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
});
```